# Loaded content and javascript asynchronous issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I replaced content from index.htm with content from project.htm. When you click on a#front it is linked on project.htm and it dynamically loads (replaces) the new content. But I have an issue with how to execute javascript that I'm loading with new content. To load script I used function *getScript*. Here is the function that I'm using to load new content and script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a#front').click(function() { 
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide("drop", { direction: "left" }, "slow", loadContent);
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad ,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show("drop", { direction: "right" }, "slow");
        $.getScript('js/project.js');
    }
    return false; 
});
```

});
Javascript that I loaded when I loaded new content only worked if I had alert at the top or this way. But when I try to load more complex content (insted just text I put div, headings etc) it doesnt work:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
        $('a#link').click(function() { 
            $("p").css("color","white");
        });
    }
});
```

Can you help me with this or maybe you have some different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem and menaged to load content from new file and also javascript for that. Notice that in new file I need to have content wrapped into div with ID *content* and I load it into div in native document, with the same name - *content*. 
Here is how I load new content and how I call new javascript files using *getScript* function:

```
$('a#front').click(function() { 
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide("drop", { direction: "left" }, "slow", loadContent);
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
        function loadContent() {
            $('#content').load(toLoad ,'',showNewContent())
        }
        function showNewContent() {
            $('#content').show("drop", { direction: "right" }, "slow");
            $.getScript('js/project.js');
            $.getScript('js/section.js');
            $.getScript('js/carousel.js');
        }
        return false; 
    });
```

To force loaded javascript execution I used *setTimeout* function. For example this is how looks code inside carousel.js file which activate carousel:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        //run carousel
        $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();    
    }, 100);    });
```

How it works you can see [here](http://valeka.net/katie/)